# Call default text selecting in Entry widget, like with pressing 'Tab'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, focus, tkinter-entry

Tkinter `Entry` widget has a built in option. If you have some `Entry` widgets in the frame, pressing `Tab`, when you `focus_set` one of the Entries, will cause switching focus between these `Entry` widgets and selecting the whole text in current focused `Entry`.

I want to force text selection on every focus changing, even with mouse click (not `Tab` only).

Is it possible to call this built-in method via binding? (I just don't want to write the similar method, as long as `Tkinter` already has one).

Using Python `3`.

Comment: Please refer to this guide on how to provide a [mre], and read about [ask]. Remember, we can't help you if we don't know what you've already tried.

Comment: I've searched in web about default bindings and how they can be called. but didn't find any info. So, i asked there.

Comment: You should look into the `'<FocusIn>'` event binding, and use that to trigger a callback function to select the text of your `Entry` widget